# How to Find the Sum of items Per Year Using Chart Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, charts, chart.js

Imagine I have an array like this :

```
["2012", "2016", "2011", "2017", "2017", "2012", "2014", "2019", "2019", "2014", "2012", "2016", "2012", 2015, "2013", "2012", "2011", "2008", 2015, "2009", "2011", "2018", "2019", "2017", 2015, "2020", "2016", "2010", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2014", "2014", "2019", "2015", "2019", "2016", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2019", "2009", "2016", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2012", "2013"]
```

How could I be able to plot this using Chart js & React.js with the x axis containing individual years and the y axis containing the number of occurrences the year is found?

Here is what I've tried:

```
let array = [["2012", "2016", "2011", "2017", "2017", "2012", "2014", "2019", "2019", "2014", "2012", "2016", "2012", 2015, "2013", "2012", "2011", "2008", 2015, "2009", "2011", "2018", "2019", "2017", 2015, "2020", "2016", "2010", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2014", "2014", "2019", "2015", "2019", "2016", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2019", "2009", "2016", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2012", "2013"];

getChartData = () => {
  console.log(array);
  this.setState({
    chartData: {
      labels: array,
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Population',
        data: array,
      }]
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: you can use react-chartjs-2 => https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-chartjs-2

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I am using that already

Comment: @DevsiOdedra I have updated the question to show you what I've tried

Comment: Could you give an example of the array for the data you would want for the y-axis? Would it be something like `[5, 6, ...etc]` since 2012 appears 5 times, 2016 appears 6 times etc... ?

Comment: @NickParsons yes that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get your y-axis array, you can use a combination of [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) with an ES6 [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The idea of a Map is similar to a regular object, it stores key-value pairs. Each key must be unique. You can use [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to accumulate/form your Map, by setting the keys to be the year from your array. If the year is already in the Map, you can increment its value which will hold the number of times that year appears. If the year isn't in the map, you can add it as a new key with a value of 1 (to indicate that year has been encountered once). You can then get the keys from the map and turn it into an array using [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to get an array of unique years. You can also get the values from the map and convert it into an array to get an array of frequencies. Each index from the xAxis array correspond will correspond to the frequency at the same index (eg: xAxisArr[0] holds "2012", so its frequency will be yAxisArr[0] (same index), which is 6).

```js
const arr = ["2012", "2016", "2011", "2017", "2017", "2012", "2014", "2019", "2019", "2014", "2012", "2016", "2012", "2015", "2013", "2012", "2011", "2008", "2015", "2009", "2011", "2018", "2019", "2017", "2015", "2020", "2016", "2010", "2013", "2017", "2018", "2014", "2014", "2019", "2015", "2019", "2016", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2019", "2009", "2016", "2014", "2015", "2015", "2015", "2016", "2012", "2013"];

const freqMap = arr.reduce(
  (map, year) => map.set(year, (map.get(year) || 0) + 1),
  new Map
);
const xAxisArr = Array.from(freqMap.keys()); // array of unique years
const yAxisArr = Array.from(freqMap.values()); // array of frequencies for each year

console.log("x axis");
console.log(xAxisArr);
console.log("y axis");
console.log(yAxisArr);
```

**Note:** I'm assuming that the literal numbers in your array that you provided such as `2015` (rather than "2015" as a string) are typos, so I have converted them in the example above. If they're not typos you can map your array to strings using `.map(String)`.